# Renewing a US Passport without getting rid of the old one

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens, passport-renewals

I have an issue with my US passport where I am running out of passport pages for stamps/visas.  My current passport expires in 2023, but I need to get a new one.

However, I recently began traveling quite often.  In particular, I do not think that there is a 2 week period I can go about daily life without my passport.  I understand that I am supposed to fill out a form and mail in my current passport, but that seems especially hard for me with my current lifestyle.

What is the best way to fix this issue?  Or, is the only solution for me to take a break from life for however long it takes to get a new passport?

Comment: You can legally get a second passport https://traveltips.usatoday.com/obtain-second-passport-legally-61904.html. You need to get very creative in articulating your reason.

Comment: Going forward, order a 52 page passport instead of the standard 24 pages. Same prices. When I was a kid I had pages added to my passport, but apparently they don't do that any more.

Comment: Have you already had pages added to your current one (or ordered a large one to begin with)? If not, that's an alternative to getting a new one that might have quicker turnaround.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get your passport [renewed the same day if you go in person to one of the government passport agency/center](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/hurry.html) like I did.

You can also [obtain a second passport legally](https://traveltips.usatoday.com/obtain-second-passport-legally-61904.html). You need to get very creative in articulating your reason.

> Proof of the upcoming trip described in your application and:
>
> - your primary passport, **if it's not with an embassy already waiting**    for a visa
> - a new passport photo, different from the one on your primary passport
> - a copy of your driver’s license or other    state-issued ID (front and back)
> - the application fee, currently

Particularly you need to let them know your current passport is with another embassy. You can creatively find a way to satisfy that easily without lying

Or the least desirable option, take a break from life.